# Ubuntu image on raspberry pi: Wifi takes long time to connect (ssh) after reboot/shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, wifi

I am using Ubiquity Robotics Raspberry Pi image (which is Ubuntu 16.04) on Raspberry pi 4B. Since installation, I noticed that the wifi takes a very long time (about 5-10 minutes) to activate for ssh. Although I can ping it almost immediately without any issues. I have searched lot of related topics but unable to find a solution that solves this particular one. I am not sure whether it is an ssh issue or a wifi connection issue as ping works fine. Any help in this regard will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the issue while reading through this [thread](https://forum.ubiquityrobotics.com/t/ros-image-on-raspberry-pi-4/326/59?u=rohbotics)

Basically, going to `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/networking.service` and then change `TimeoutStartSec=5mi` to `TimeoutStartSec=10sec`

As this is not Raspberry Pi issue, therefore anyone who is having similar issues with Ubuntu may find this answer helpful.

Comment: I really hate this overengineered thing called systemd. Thanks !